# What are the internal and external databases that can be used with Android, Windows Phone and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, database, windows-phone-7, mobile

I want to know what are the internal and external databases that I can use with each mobile OS.

Comment: Realm is suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is included in [iOS](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) and [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html). There is also a [CodePlex library](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/) for using Sqlite on Windows Phone (the built in database is Sql CE)

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is a popular choice for each of them.  It's light-weight, with all the database access in-process, and the storage in a single file (plus journal).

It is included in the iOS and [Android](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html&ei=jLoHT6D_Fafq0gG9uaSgAg&usg=AFQjCNGHrlZI8DewY8QwqR2vRa37N2GJpg&sig2=5kH9kd6aOCLvnAXz3n3Vjw) SDKs.  There are distributions for [Windows Phone 7](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite%20windows%20phone%207&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=iceweasel-a).

Generally, you will not use external databases per se, though of course it is common to use internet APIs (which in turn will usually use databases)

Answer (score 1):

External database SQLite works on: iOS,Android and Windows phone.

Internal Database:

1) CoreData and NSUserDefault memory cache for iOS .

2) Isolated Storage for Windows phone (http://winphone7db.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Sybase SQL Anywhere Studio has [UltraLite](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1002288#ultralite) database as a part.
This database has versions running on Windows Mobile, iOS, Android, Blackberry, and lets you [synchronize](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1091125#UL) through HTTP/HTTPS (as far as I know, you can use Windows Mobile databases on Windows Phone)

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.jstorage.info/ so i don't even need to write code for each kind of system.
jQuery plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET programming on Windows Mobile and Windows Phone, you could use [TurboDB](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html) or [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/).