# Different Mobile OS and Databases

Tags: android, ios, database, windows-phone-7, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the internal and external databases that can be used with Android, Windows Phone and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767074/what-are-the-internal-and-external-databases-that-can-be-used-with-android-wind)

I'm doing a little research for my company and trying to find out what databases are used for the different Mobile OS. For Android and iOS it's SQLite, but whats about Black Berry and Windows Mobile?

My boss is scared that there might be some major changes on the used database, so he wants to store all static data in files, instead of tables. Do you have any arguments to show that this fear is absolutely unfounded?

Comment: Blackberry has an official SQLIte implementation and WP7 has opensource implemntations (the official database technology for WP is not SQLite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Mobile allows you to add SQLite [if needed](http://blog.tallan.com/2009/12/31/adding-sqlite-to-a-windows-mobile-application/).As for Blackberry, it's native and the developer doc is [available here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36691/Storing_data_in_SQLite_databases_1554272_11.jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Sybase SQL Anywhere Studio has [UltraLite](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1002288#ultralite) database as a part.
This database has versions running on Windows Mobile, iOS, Android, Blackberry, and lets you [synchronize](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1091125#UL) through HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: Windows Mobile, but not Windows Phone 7

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Mobile and Windows Phone you can use [TurboDB](http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html) if you program in .NET.